# Passing a variable to the next view from a List row. SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, gridview, modalviewcontroller

Hi Im new To SwiftUI I created a table using List and Grid/GridRow. The table is populated by a simple model Players. That just has the players first name, last name and score. When the users clicks on a particular players row the app should open up a Modal View and display information about that particular player.

The problem I am having is no matter which row is clicked the Modal view shows the information for the first player. At this point Im just passing the first name over to the Modal View. When I print to console the variable being passed to the Modal it shows the correct name based on the row clicked. But the console view will only show the name in the first row.

The first row the name is "Roy" on the second row its "Richard". If I click row 2. the console prints out "Richard" but the Modal view says "Roy"

here is my code
import SwiftUI

```
    struct PlayerView: View {

    let players = [
        Players(firstName: "Roy", lastName: "Kent",score:100),
        Players(firstName: "Richard", lastName: "Montlaur",score:100),
        Players(firstName: "Dani", lastName: "Rojas",score:100)
    ]
    @State private var showingReportCard = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List{
                Grid{
                    GridRow {
                        Text("First Name")
                        Text("Last Name")
                        Text("Score")
                    }
                    Divider()
                    ForEach(players){
                        player in
                        GridRow {
                            Text(player.firstName)
                            Text(player.lastName)
                            Text("\(player.score)")
                        }.onTapGesture {
                       
                        showingReportCard.toggle()
                        print(player.firstName)
                        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingReportCard) {
                        TutoringView(firstName:player.firstName)
                        }
                    }
                
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `onTap`, assign the value to an optional `@State` variable, (ie `selectedPlayer`) then when you present the sheet, pass that through to the next view.  Typically I would use `didSet` on the `selectedPlayer` player to also toggle the `showingReportCard` so you don't need to remember to do it

Comment: You could also look at the `sheet(item: Binding?...)` variant, which would exclude the need for a boolean property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use .sheet(item: ...) and also moving this sheet call to the NavigationStack.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        PlayerView()
    }
}

struct Players: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var score: Int
}

struct PlayerView: View {
    let players = [
        Players(firstName: "Roy", lastName: "Kent",score:100),
        Players(firstName: "Richard", lastName: "Montlaur",score:100),
        Players(firstName: "Dani", lastName: "Rojas",score:100)
    ]

    @State private var selectedPlayer: Players?  // <---
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List{
                Grid{
                    GridRow {
                        Text("First Name")
                        Text("Last Name")
                        Text("Score")
                    }
                    Divider()
                    ForEach(players){ player in
                        GridRow {
                            Text(player.firstName)
                            Text(player.lastName)
                            Text("\(player.score)")
                        }.onTapGesture {
                            print(player.firstName)
                            selectedPlayer = player  // <---
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedPlayer) { player in  // <---
            TutoringView(firstName: player.firstName)
        }
    }
}

struct TutoringView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var firstName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(firstName)
        Button("dismiss") {
            dismiss()
        }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
}
```